# Angular doesn't update Values in FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to fill a form Group which contains a form array with dynamic length. A dropdown with multiple selection determines how many arrays are created. There are new dropdowns for each created array. But only the values for the last dropdown are added to the form.

I am using Angular 11.0.5

I used [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bhjdhb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as a reference but it doesn't yield the same output for me.

My Form

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  parents: [[]],
  children: this.fb.array([])
});
```

How I create the arrays within `children` on changed values in `parents`

```js
get formChildren(): FormArray {
  return this.form.get('children') as FormArray;
}
addArrays(number){
  this.formChildren.clear();
  Array<Datatype>(number).fill(null).map(() => this.formChildren.push(this.fb.control([])));
}
```

My HTML looks like this

```html
<form [formGroup]="metaDataChangeFormGroup">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [multiple]="true" formControlName="parents">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let parent of parents [value]="parent">
            {{ parent }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <ng-container formArrayName="children">
    <mat-form-field *ngFor="let parent of formParents.value; let i = index">
      <mat-select
         [multiple]="true"
         [placeholder]="i.toString()"
         [formControlName]="i">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let child of childrenFacade.select()>
          <mat-option *ngIf="child && child.parent.id == parent.id"
                [value]="child">
                {{ child }}
          </mat-option>
        </ng-container>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

This works so far that the dropdown for the children of the last selected parent get saved in the correct array, but not for the other dropdowns. When I subscribe to `valuesChanged` on the `formChildren` it gets triggered as i made a console log, but the array in the form stays empty. The complete form is printed out on my component. Why does it work for the last parent and not the rest?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you want to select a parent and have a variable amount of children for the parent, but the whole data structure should be saved? If this is the case you need to have a `formArray` with children per parent! Not one `formArray` for all parents, that you delete after switching the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you mean that. Also, how come it works as intended for the last parent but not for the others?

Comment: Look at your code! If the parent is switched `this.formChildren.clear();` is called, deleting the content for the previous parent. So it makes perfect sense that only the last selected parent works.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean now! What would you suggest to do so the selected children are set to null when changing the Parents selection?

Answer (score 0):

You want your form to look something like this:

```js
this.form = this.fb.array([
  this.fb.group({
    parent: []
    children: this.fb.array([])
  }),
  this.fb.group({
    parent: []
    children: this.fb.array([])
  }),
]);
```

With this you can maintain form controls for every child of every parent. I just added 2 parents as an example. Of course in your code you need to generate the `FormGroup`s dynamically.

Here is your [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-39o5rz) modified to showcase the behaviour.

Comment: I have tried doing so, but I don't manage to make it work. I want the dropdown for the children only shown and required only if a parent was selected. How can insert one parent into your `formGroup`? How do the HTML bindings need to be set for this to work?

Comment: I added a Stackblitz showcasing the behaviour.